# Common mode filtering for three DC lines

Tags: filter, noise, passive-filter, common-mode, emi-filtering

I want to filter common mode noise on three DC lines: +5V, GND, -5V at 1A.

Why are there so few options for common mode chokes with three lines? What is a good topology for this situation when using common mode chokes with two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If +5 V and -5 V are regulated outputs of 1 or 2 DC/DC converters than I would use a CMF on the power supply input line.

If not, then you need two CMF. The first between +5 V and GND. The second between -5 V and GND.

If your design is committed to high production volume, then I suggest you to find a Taiwanese manufacturer and buy directly from them.

Cost of 1 Ampere CMF toroidal ring.

0.19 USD @3k parts for small toroidal rings.

0.39 USD @3k for large toroidal rings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll definitely look up Taiwanese manufacturers.

Comment: I guess I'll have to design in both CMF since there's 1m wire between the regulated output and the input, and noise is expected to be an issue

Comment: Go to an EMC lab and do some tests as I did. Bring many CMF samples, a solder iron and a dummy load that draws 1 A. In my case, I had to shorten my 2 output cables by one third in order for my product to be compliant.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why are there so few options for common mode chokes with three lines?
> What is a good topology for this situation when using common mode
> chokes with two lines?*

Common mode chokes on two lines by their very nature cancel differential current MMFs from the load and therefore, can be made from much smaller ferrite components. How would these cancel with three wires and two loads? You’d have to rate the ferrites to be able to handle a far bigger standing MMF and that is of course not a great solution in many respects.

Of course there may be ones that can handle two separate current loops but they are few and far between I’d say.

Comment: I guess that's why 3-line chokes tend to have a low current rating, thanks!

Comment: You can get them for balanced line conditions like three phase power systems. There may be other reasons of course they aren’t more often seen but that’s the best reason I can see @ab2